# 'The provided ARN is invalid' error when locally running a Step Function that calls EventBridge Scheduler

Tags: scheduler, aws-step-functions, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3, aws-stepfunctions-local

I am running a Step Function using the AWS JS SDK v3 that gets and creates schedules with AWS EventBridge Scheduler. When I run it in the AWS account, I am able to run the step function.

However, when I set the `endpoint` to 'http://stepfunctions:8083', which is where the [amazon/stepfunctions-local](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-stepfunctions-local/tags) Docker container is running, I get the following error:

`An error occurred while scheduling the state 'GetSchedule'. The provided ARN 'arn:aws:states:***********:aws-sdk:scheduler:getSchedule' is invalid.;`

Following this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-docker.html) to run the step function locally, I have defined a mock (using [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-mock-cfg-file.html)) for the step that invokes EventBridge Scheduler. With the mock, I get the following error:

`An error occurred while scheduling the state 'GetSchedule'. Could not find scheduler:getSchedule as aws sdk. Please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-supported-services.html for valid service ARNs.`

For many other step functions I have that are not calling EventBridge Scheduler or any other services that were supported around the same time (Feb 2023, as listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html#supported-services-awssdk-list)), the SDK and the mocking framework work fine.

Things I have tried:

- Using the latest version Docker image for [stepfunctions-local](https://hub.docker.com/layers/amazon/aws-stepfunctions-local/1.13.2/images/sha256-8867d8418b35ad1960f2891d149d55824b085f10c31a4f22c7d45dfbe7fdf784?context=explore)
- Updating the `@aws-sdk/client-sfn` version to the latest i.e. `^3.478.0`
- Installing `@aws-sdk/client-scheduler` along with all the other packages in the docker container where the tests are running

Here is my step function:

```
{
  "Comment": "Sample step func that fetches a schedule",
  "StartAt": "GetSchedule",
  "States": {
    "GetSchedule": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "my_sched_name"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:scheduler:getSchedule"
    }
  }
}
```

My tests:

```
describe(`StepFunctions/${stepFunctionName}`, function () {
    let sfnWithDefinition;
    let sfnDirectlyOnAwsAccount;

    before(async () => {
        // The `StepFunction` class is just a helper that wraps AWS sfn-client commands
        sfnWithDefinition = new StepFunction({
            name: stepFunctionNameBase,
            definition: templatefile(
                `${stepFunctionsPath}/${stepFunctionName}.asl.json`,
                {},
            ),
        });
        await sfnWithDefinition.create();
        sfnDirectlyOnAwsAccount = new StepFunction({
            name: stepFunctionNameBase,
            mode: ExecutionMode.OnAwsAccount,
        });
    });


    it('step function when run locally WITHOUT mock returns error: The provided ARN \'arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:671446661642:aws-sdk:scheduler:getSchedule\' is invalid', async () => {
        const {response, history} = await sfnWithDefinition.execute({});
        console.log('history', history);
        const executionFailureDetails = getExecutionFailedDetails(history);
        const failureMessage = constructFailureMessage(executionFailureDetails);
        console.warn(failureMessage);
    });
    it('step function when run locally WITH mock returns error: Could not find scheduler:getSchedule as aws sdk. Please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-supported-services.html for valid service ARNs.', async () => {
        const {response, history} = await sfnWithDefinition.execute({}, 'Mocking');
        console.log('history', history);
        const executionFailureDetails = getExecutionFailedDetails(history);
        const failureMessage = constructFailureMessage(executionFailureDetails);
        console.warn(failureMessage);
    });


    it('step function without definition with only ARN runs successfully on sandbox', async () => {
        const exc = await sfnDirectlyOnAwsAccount.executeOnCloud(sfnArn, {});
        console.log(exc);
        //EXECUTION IS CREATED SUCCESSFULLY IN AWS ACCOUNT
    });

    it('scheduler sdk directly fetches the schedule successfully', async () => {
        const schedConfig = {
            region: config.aws.region,
        };
        const client = new SchedulerClient(schedConfig);
        const input = {
            Name: "my_sched_name",
        };
        const command = new GetScheduleCommand(input);
        const response = await client.send(command);

        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

**Question**: Is there a way to make the step function be run locally when the step function invokes `scheduler:*` resources? Or is it a known missing feature in the amazon/stepfunctions-local?
I couldn't find anything in the docs of the Docker image.

Alternatively, is there a workaround for this - e.g. another framework, or using HTTP integration instead of aws-sdk to call EventBridge Scheduler?